# How to search string only from Contact field and popup using sforce.interaction.searchAndScreenPop?

Tags: apex, visualforce, developer-console, opencti

I wanted to search string and wanted to popup the screen for string.
I can do this by using sforce.interaction.searchAndScreenPop open CTI.
but issue is that this api searches string in all objects like case, account, leads etc.
I wanted to search the string only in Contact object.

How can I achieve this ?

Could you let me know about searchparma of this api ? 
like which parameter can i use for search ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This function is documented by sfdc here:

> http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_cti/Content/sforce_api_cti_searchandscreenpop.htm

But this does not contain a clear example indeed.

To search only in Contact, you should be able to use this syntax:

```
sforce.interaction.searchAndScreenPop('111-111-1111', 'object=Contact', 'inbound', callback);
```